# Допустимо ли сочетание «симпатичная красавица»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Допустимо ли сочетание «симпатичная красавица»?

Например, есть выражение «холодная красота», а в случае, когда имеется в виду красота миловидная и т. п., можно ли применять словосочетание «симпатичная красавица», либо это «масло масляное», потому как синонимы?

Comment: Почему, если "несимпатичная (=маловысокообаятельная) красавица" вполне можно обыграть контекстом, то мой вариант недопустим? И нормы, правила русского языка ведь не строятся на том, кому как прийдет в голову обыграть контекст...Интересует ответ, основанный именно на них...

Comment: >> *Почему, если "несимпатичная (=маловысокообаятельная) красавица" вполне можно обыграть контекстом, то мой вариант недопустим?* Да и этот вариант ("несимпатичная красавица") вряд ли допустим.

Answer (score 3):

Это не «масло масляное» (плеоназм), не синонимы, но эти слова плохо сочетаются.  Возможно, это даже можно считать речевой ошибкой.

Давайте разберемся.

1. Оба слова характеризуют внешность. Важно подчеркнуть, что слово "симпатичная" в данном контексте соответствует п. 2 ниже (милый, привлекательный), в отличие от "мне симпатична", выражающего отношение к человеку (п. 1 ниже).
2. "Красавица" — характеристика более сильная, чем "симпатичная". Поэтому "симпатичная красавица" звучит нелепо, как например "сообразительный гений". Посмотрел в Нацкорпусе: там нет такого сочетания.

> [СИМПАТИЧНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x), -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. 1. Вызывающий симпатию, располагающий (противоп.: антипатичный). Они, кажется, люди с-ые. Ты мне симпатичен. Ваши намерения мне очень симпатичны. 2. Милый, привлекательный. Вокруг с-ые юные лица. Хозяйка ведёт симпатичного пуделя. Какая с-ая мордашка! С-ая у тебя подружка! Какой с. кружевной воротничок, просто загляденье! Девочка нянчила симпатичного плюшевого медвежонка. Мы остановились у симпатичного домика с резными наличниками. <Симпатичность, -и; ж. При всей его симпатичности что-то в нём настораживает.

Comment: Есть игра с таким названием http://itsmygame.ru/999972369/simpatichnaja-krasavica-9_online-game.html

Comment: @Sharon Мой комп блокирует этот адрес. Как называется игра?

Comment: Игра Симпатичная красавица 9

Comment: @Sharon И каково Ваше мнение?

Comment: Об игре? Я там ничего не поняла. Я думаю, что грамматическое  СОЧЕТАНИЕ  этих двух слов достаточно условно. Для игры, может, и подойдет, но в реальной  жизни вряд ли встречается. Но вот наличие  двух качеств у меня не вызывает сомнение: есть красота добрая. притягательная, озаренная внутренним светом, такая вызывает у людей симпатию. А есть красота холодная, способная вызвать равнодушие или даже неприязнь.

Answer (score 1):

Не-а. Холодная красота ни при чём, а красавица, она и в Африке красавица.

> [Симпатичная? – Красавица.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=p7jzCXHB7kcC&pg=PT239&lpg=PT239&dq=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=Z9G01OIhne&sig=fqe36OlYEe2E7f8idtvGdVXJvN8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS8IfSk93fAhVBEywKHZ2EDgYQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) – Сколько лет? – Двадцать. – Не пойдет.
>   Москвичка, да еще и красавица! – Чего же тебе надо? – удивился
>   Алексей. – Жену.

То есть - отнюдь не синонимы, ни в коей мере не масло масляное... к антонимам даже поближе будет.

Однако сочетание "несимпатичная (=маловысокообаятельная) красавица" вполне можно обыграть контекстом.

Несимпатичными красавицами в фильмах были Лидия Вертинская (Анидаг, Феникс), Варлей (Панночка), Алтайская ("Светлый путь").

---

Подпризадумалась над последней фамилией...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли представить, что девушке со снимка предстоит играть одних мерзких гадин (Шкипидар в "Евдокии", Асырк в "Королевстве кривых зеркал", мачеха в "Морозко"...)

> ...Актрисе поступает предложение участвовать в съемках картины,
>   которую снимает сам Григорий Александров. В 1940-м маэстро работал над
>   фильмом «Светлый путь». Он утвердил [молодую Алтайскую на роль
>   стильной красавицы](https://www.syl.ru/article/287845/new_vera-altayskaya-aktrisa-s-bolshoy-bukvyi) Клавдии, которая жила по соседству с главной
>   героиней...

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Лидия Вертинская в фильме *Садко*, 1952](https://kulturologia.ru/blogs/140417/34166/)

---

Ну и Панночку до кучи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

"Красавица" - это качество,  принадлежащие человеку,  а "симпатия" -  наше отношение к нему. 
"Эта красавица мне симпатична," - звучит вполне логично, так как выражает моё полное отношение к данной женщине,  либо девушке.  Симпатия возникает не только на основании внешних качеств, но и внутренних - душевных.  Ваше выражение, в принципе, допустимо, просто оно не совсем благозвучно.

Comment: В чем "неблагозвучие"? Неблагозвучность - это вот что:

*Позаботься о благозвучии фразы, у тебя ж опыта больше.*

Comment: О вашей фразе давно позаботились. Она притендует скорее на юмор, а не на какое-либо "звучие". О "симпатичной красавеце" я лишь высказал своё скромное мнение.

Comment: Нет, это именно неблагозвучие. А что же тогда вы называете неблагозвучием?

Comment: То, что не благо для звучания.

Answer (score 0):

Это примерно то же, что *неплохой шедевр*. Что-то похожее на оксюморон, но не он.

Comment: А всё же какие то конкретные правила русского языка могут вынести однозначный вердикт?

Comment: Это же не грамматика, какие тут могут быть правила? Вот, например, писатель Андрей Платонов писал чудовищно тяжелым языком, но по части грамматики к нему претензий нет. Думаю, он мог бы такое написать.

Comment: "Симпатичный шедевр" — еще ближе к теме. Миленький такой шедевр, приятненький, гармонирует с обоями на стене.

Comment: А разве нормы и правила русского языка - это только грамматика?

Comment: В любом случае есть же стилистические нормы, как тогда с этой точки зрения? Есть ли четкие границы?

Comment: Ну, подумайте: возможно ли нормировать все словосочетания? Ясно, что можно придумать контекст (допустим, иронический), где это словосочетание будет вполне на месте. Вне контекста звучит, мягко говоря, странно.